# Is using a scroll view cancelling a child recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have read that using `ScrollView` generally is not a good idea.
But I have a custom view that takes e.g. 300dp width and bellow it a recycler view.
If I do not add these in a `ScrollView` the recycler view takes only what's left of the 300dp.
So in this case is using `ScrollView` correct or it somehow cancels out the benefit of using a recycler view?

Answer (score 0):

for a better scrolling behavior you will need to set nested scrolling off for `RecyclerView` but it will still recycle views if you use it inside of `NestedScrollView`

Comment: And how do I that?

Comment: `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` @Jim

Comment: How does that help? I don't see any visual issue with scrolling now. Is it a memory management trick?

Comment: When you have multiple scrolling Views in your layout (eg. RecyclerView + ScrollView) and when you scroll while in your recyclerView, the recyclerView scrolls with the parent Scrollview. this causes jitters in RecyclerView @Jim